# SCOM C# how to get sharepoint's outgoing parameters

Tags: email, scom

I would like to get the paramaters shown in the following picture. can this been done and how?

Thank you

P.S. I wonder if it's possible to send email using scom and Sharepoint email system.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code for that

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    string smtpHost = site.WebApplication.OutboundMailServiceInstance.Parent.Name
    string fromEmail = site.WebApplication.OutboundMailSenderAddress
}
```

Or

```
var admin = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPGlobalAdmin()
var server = admin.OutboundSmtpServer
var replyToAddress = admin.MailReplyToAddress
var fromAddress = admin.MailFromAddress
```